# Keyboard shortcut to close all tabs without closing Firefox

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a keyboard shortcut to close all open tabs without closing Firefox?

In fact, I want Firefox not to close when all tabs are closed. There may be a new blank tab after all tabs are closed.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the instructions in this post to configure FireFox to not close the window when the last tab is closed:

[(Don’t) Close Firefox with Last Tab](http://coffeeonthekeyboard.com/dont-close-firefox-with-last-tab-296/)

If you hold CTRL + W all tabs will close very quickly, when the last one is closed, you will get the default tab that is there when you open FireFox.